# Why can I not access var i like this and how do I work around it?

Tags: javascript

I was just fiddling around and was just wondering if it would be possible to access the I variable somehow in this loop.

```
var string = 'abcdefghij';
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    window[string[i]] = function(){
        console.log(i);
    };
}
a();
```

Obviously for many reasons I wouldn't do this with the global scope normally, but I'd like to use this as an example.

Would there be a way to still access the `i var` from inside this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `i` in another scope, where it is not defined.

**This is not completly correct yet:**

```js
var string = 'abcdefghij';
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  window[string[i]] = (function(i) {
    return function() {
      console.log(i);
    }
  })(i);
}
a()
```

This self-executing function will basicly copy the variable `i` into it's own scope, so it can be used later on.

But, when you try to execture the function `i` above you will notive that it throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: i is not a function`. This is because you are using the same global variable in the for loop `var i` as you are setting the function `i` to. To avoid this problem use the same trick again around the loop. However be warned, as soon as you use a for loop or any global variable again that has the same name as one one the dynamicly defined function, you will get unexpected problems again.

```js
var string = 'abcdefghij';
(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    window[string[i]] = (function(i) {
      return function() {
        console.log(i);
      }
    })(i);
  }
})();

i()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like the a function can be accessed. I am doing something wrong I suppose.

Comment: You cannot use `i` in your string in your case it is being override by the `i` of the loop. You will not have its `function`.

Comment: I just tried your code and it works like a charm. Cheers mate. Would you normally suggest against dynamically creating functions like this?(aside from the window object?)

Comment: @Puddingboy If possible it would be cleaner and easyer to debug in bigger projects, to define normal function. But if you have a usecase for this, do it ;)

Comment: Indeed `i();` , `j();` and `h();` are not working. Would this have anything to do with not being able to override these window objects?

Comment: I tried your code, but it comes to `i()` it doesn't identify the function. It works fine from `a()` to  `h()`. Its being override by inner loop `i` I think. If you remove `i` from your string, everything goes fine.

Comment: @Shaharyar that's a very good point! And maybe a reason why not to use dynamic functions like this.

Comment: Exactly ! I would appreciate if you explain it in your answer for future references.

Comment: I this case I was using letters of the alphabet to create a quick draft. In practice I would probably use a `for( var key in obj )` loop on an object with the names I intend to use. You could add it to your example, but I can't say if it would be better or not.

Comment: @Puddingboy you might still use the same names for any variable or other function by mistake. It's dangerous, but as I said, if you have a good reason to use it you can do it. Another way could be to assign the function to another object, like `var myFunctions = {}` and then use them like that `myFunction.i()` or `myFunction["i"]()`

Comment: @CodeiSir I was thinking of doing that anyways. My current approach was meant to simplify my example, but in this case it may have actually created more confusion instead. I'll try to keep it in mind for other questions.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of `var`. And it's a good pratice. With `let`, variables are defined within the closest block scope. As a result, they will not be overwritten after each iteration.

```js
'use strict';
var string = 'abcdefghij';
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  window[string[i]] = function() {
    console.log(i);
  };
}
a(); //0
```

Comment: I agree with CodeiSir https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 0):

Use Closures Technique you can do like this.As we pass scope of 'i' to inner function and that immediately call itself.

```
 var string = 'abcdefghij';
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  window[string[i]] = (function(i) {
    return function() {
      console.log(i);
    }
  })(i);
}
a()
```

Comment: It seems your code also doesn't have a working a function